# angularjs passing variables into controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have my angular controller setup like most of the examples shown in the docs such that it is a global function. I assume that the controller class is being called when the angular engine sees the controller tag in the html.

My issue is that i want to pass in a parameter to my controller and i don't know how to do that because I'm not initializing it. I see some answers suggesting the use of ng-init. But my parameter is not a trivial string - it is a complex object that is being loaded by another (non-angular) part of my js. It is also not available right on load but takes a while to come along.

So i need a way to pass this object, when it finally finishes loading, into the controller (or scope) so that the controller can interact with it.
Is this possible?

Comment: You could create a basket service. And generally in JS you use objects instead of lots of parameters. http://jsfiddle.net/gVEq5/

Comment: Have a look on the tutorial page about services: http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_11

Comment: and i also see how a service could be used to call out for a file or for an http request using $resource or $http. But again, not exactly my situation. I'm basically wanting a resource from another area of my js code. seems like i either inject it into the controller somehow or the controller calls out for it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a service or a factory for this, combined with promises:

You can setup a factory that returns a promise, and create a global function (accessible from 3rd-party JS) to resolve the promise.

Note the `$rootScope.$apply()` call. Angular won't call the `then` function of a promise until an `$apply` cycle. See the [`$q` docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24q).

```
app.factory('fromoutside', function($window, $q, $rootScope) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    $window.injectIntoAngularWorld = function(obj) {
        deferred.resolve(obj);
        $rootScope.$apply();
    };

    return deferred.promise;
});
```

And then in your controller, you can ask for the `fromoutside` service and bind to the data when it arrives:

```
app.controller('main', function($scope, fromoutside) {
    fromoutside.then(function(obj) {
        $scope.data = obj;
    });
});
```

And then somewhere outside of Angular:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    window.injectIntoAngularWorld({
        A: 1,
        B: 2,
        C: 3
    });
}, 2000);
```

[Here's a fiddle of this](http://jsfiddle.net/hVX7a/1/).

Personally, I feel this is a little bit cleaner than reaching into an Angular controller via the DOM.

#### EDIT: Another approach

Mark Rajcok asked in a comment if this could be modified to allow getting data more than once.

Now, getting data more than once could mean incremental updates, or changing the object itself, or other things. But the main things that need to happen are getting the data into the Angular world and then getting the right angular scopes to run their `$digest`s.

[In this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Td7jP/1/), I've shown one way, when you might just be getting updates to an Array from outside of angular.

It uses a similar trick as the promise example above.

Here's the main factory:

```
app.factory('data', function($window) {
  var items = [];
  var scopes = [];

  $window.addItem = function(item) {
    items.push(item);
    angular.forEach(scopes, function(scope) {
        scope.$digest();
    });
  };

  return {
    items: items,
    register: function(scope) { scopes.push(scope); }
};
```

Like the previous example, we attach a function to the `$window` service (exposing it globally). The new bit is exposing a `register` function, which controllers that want updates to `data` should use to register themselves.

When the external JS calls into angular, we just loop over all the registered scopes and run a digest on each to make sure they're updated.

Comment: +1 This is a nice solution.  Do you know how it could be modified to allow the data (from outside) to be modified more than once?  E.g., suppose I have a bunch of JavaScript code that interacts with an external server that I'm not able/ready/willing to port to AngularJS.  This code might get data more than once, so it would be nice if I could call injectIntoAngularWorld() more than once.

Comment: @MarkRajcok I've edited my answer to include another `factory` based approach that lets you handle updates.

Comment: Thank you for the update.  I like what you have but I would make a small tweak:  I'd use $rootScope instead of registration, just so I wouldn't have to remember to register or have to keep track of registrations:  http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/Td7jP/2/

Comment: That works, too. The reason I used the registration approach is that calling `$digest` process all of the `$watch` watchers on a scope and all of its children. Doing it on the `$rootScope` in a larger application potentiall has performance implications.

Comment: i wound up trying to blend this approach with the $q deferred because i want to know exactly when this information is ready from the outside.

Comment: @satchmorun, this is probably more for the benefit of other readers: an Igor quote (from google groups): "You should always use $apply() instead of $digest(), digest will flush only the current scope and all of its child scopes, so if your action changes any of the parent scopes, the change will not be observed.  Calling $apply on any scope is equivalent to $rootScope.$digest(); "  I think "always" is a little strong, but calling $rootScope.$digest (or $apply) is safer and more maintainable.  Calling $scope.$digest is faster, but it could bite you down the road.

Answer (score 5):

In your non-angular JavaScript, you can get access to the scope associated with a DOM element as follows:

```
angular.element(someDomElement).scope().someControllerFunction(delayedData);
```

I assume you can find someDomElement with a jQuery selector or something.

Comment: that sounds like exactly what i need but i can't get it to fly.http://jsfiddle.net/Vbahole22/2mmE6/

Comment: Okay, I messed up.  That gives you the controller instance, but not the scope associated with the controller, which is what the methods are defined on.  I'll try to come up with a real answer.