# angularjs defer then only being called once

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using the window object and a defer in order to inject some content into my controller that is not available at the time i create it. This is working fine the first time i call it - the .then method is being executed just fine. But when i call it subsequent times the .then method is not firing. What could cause this?

```
app.factory('fromoutside', function ($window, $q, $rootScope) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    $window.injectIntoAngularWorld = function (obj) {
        deferred.resolve(obj);
        $rootScope.$apply();
    };

    return deferred.promise;
});
```

This is a fiddle that sort of simulates what i'm doing but not exactly. It throws errors about apply already in progress, but then again, i get those alot and ignore them quite often [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vbahole22/Dw2Tg/)

Comment: Why do you say that method runAgain doesnt get fired again?

Comment: shouldn't i see 4,5,6 in the result instead of 1,2,3?

Comment: Why are you adding the deferred to `$window` rather than injecting the service into your controller? BTW: "$digest already in progress" is *not* a normal error and is definitely one you shouldn't ignore. It indicates there is something wrong with your code.

Comment: maybe this one makes it clearer http://jsfiddle.net/Vbahole22/Dw2Tg/2/

Comment: this example is an over simplification of what i'm trying to get done. in my real world example the 'outside' component is another js file that calls that window method.

Comment: the setup i have is working well in other areas of my code and was hatched here -  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14945177/angularjs-passing-variables-into-controller

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're probably going to be better off using an event for this sort of thing.

Promises are made to be resolved and then they're done. So that means they're kind of a one shot deal.

Here's what I'm proposing:

```js
//set it up in your run block.
app.run(function($rootScope, $window) {
   $window.foo = function (data) {
        $rootScope.$broadcast('fooCalled', data);
   };
});


//use $on in your controller.
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope){ 
   $scope.$on('fooCalled', function(event, data) {
      $scope.fooData = data;
   });
});
```

This is just *one* way to do it, but it should work, and it's fairly clean. If you wanted to create a service to listen to the event and set it up, you could.

Comment: whether its `$rootScope.$emit` or `$rootScope.broadcast`. Could you pls. clarify.

Comment: My bad, it should be $broadcast... as it's going downward to all child scopes.

Comment: what is my 'run block'? the objective is to inject a value from non-angular code into my controller. my running code (that fires the event) does not have a notion of $

Comment: I got it. Thank you very much, this is a nice solution.

Comment: One thing that is a little odd - when fooCalled is caught in the $on listener the value of data is not what i passed into foo. It appears to be the entire scope.

Comment: I think the line should read $scope.$on('fooCalled', function(event, data)

Comment: You're correct, I forget the event object. That's what I get for answering two quickly... two mistakes in one answer. :\ haha.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I fixed it by definin de deferred each time , i guess for you would be something like this :

```
$window.injectIntoAngularWorld = function (obj) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    deferred.resolve(obj);
    $rootScope.$apply();
};
```